# Explanation of -hmac flag in open SSL

Tags: openssl

I came across the following command for unix on binance which I was trying to unpack. See here: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

(Section: SIGNED Endpoint Examples for POST /api/v1/order)

`openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac`

What I understand is it is a call to the openssl command to produce a digest, the digest will be of the sha256 variety as agreed on by standard specs. What I don't understand is the `-hmac` flag. What is it and what does it do down to a mathematical level?

### My Attempt at Solving the Problem:

I did a google search with `openssl -hmac` and `openssl dgst -hmac` but the top 10 results were of not avail to me. So I imagine more experienced users would be better to ask.

### Updates:

The flag isnt mentioned in these docs: https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/openssl_dgst.1.asp and so I'm starting to believe it may have no cryptographic purpose. Although i'm right now not sure.

I found what looks similar to the flag mentioned in This Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285059/hmac-sha1-in-bash

Comment: MKS appears to be way out of date, but [the website of the OpenSSL project shows this option](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/dgst.html) and the OpenSSL-released man pages have done so for many years.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I've found an interesting post by jww on StackOverflow and updated my answer with it. The answer is surprising to say the least.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HMAC is also called a keyed hash. So you can only generate the same hash during verification if you have the same key used during signature generation. The result of the MAC is called an *authentication tag*.

HMAC is a special construct that uses two calls to the hash - in your case SHA-256 - that is used internally, and it doesn't use any other *cryptographic primitives*. It could therefore be seen as a specific *mode* of the hash itself. Hence the inclusion in *dgst*.

Missing from your code is the key data, which is of course required to create a keyed hash. This should be presented after `-hmac`. Unfortunately `openssl` requires a binary format of the key. For more info see [this old conversation on the OpenSSL mailing list](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/OpenSSL-command-line-HMAC-td22242.html).

EDIT #1: Digging a bit deeper, if you want to specify the key as hexadecimals you could use a line like this:

```
echo -n "Hello world!" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac hmac -macopt hexkey:01020304
```

The output of the function is the output of the second run of the hash, so it is indistinguishable from just SHA-256 if you just look at the size of the hash / HMAC result. Of course the contents will be completely different from just hashing the data (or key and data concatenated).

---

**EDIT #2: However, you haven't specified a key, so actually HMAC is skipped and SHA-256 is used. This has been flagged as a bug, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492833/what-key-is-used-by-openssl-command-for-hmac-if-key-is-not-passed-in-as-argume)**

Comment: In this API (following the link) they use an ASCII form key, ( a long base64 string) which is then used as an argument after `-hmac`. If you wanted to use binary keys, you'd have to convert them to hex-strings (as in the `enc -K` option) and use an alternative form of the command `openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:ABCDEF0102` e.g.

Comment: Of course, entropy-wise it doesn't matter if we use an ASCII-fied key NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j or the equivalent 48 raw bytes. It's common practice in such API-calls to base64 everything so that string methods (or arguments) just work. HTTP prefers ASCII too (for the API keys in headers, etc.)

Comment: If someone is using this command to validate libcrypto code, don't forget that if you have `const unsigned char data[]  = "Hello world!"` then the command should have `echo -ne "Hello world!\0"` with the explicit null terminator.

Answer (score -1):

my 2 cents if You are on iOS (or Mac OS...)
tired of messing around I wrote it..

https://apps.apple.com/it/app/hmac-sha256generator/id6448465719?l=en